# How to parse JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was trying to parse JSON array in AngularJS. But it's not working. If the array is written directly it's working. Help me to solve the issue. The code I have been using is below.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', ['ngCookies']);

    app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $cookies) {
        $scope.products = JSON.parse(SuccessItems);
        $scope.cart = [];
        $scope.total = 0;
        var expireDate = new Date();
        expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
        $cookies.putObject('cart', $scope.cart, { 'expires': expireDate });
        $scope.cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');
        $scope.total += parseFloat(product.price);
        $cookies.put('total', $scope.total, { 'expires': expireDate });
    };
    }]);

    var SuccessItems = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.aspx/RetrieveItems",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (jsondata) {
            SuccessItems = jsondata.d.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:').replace(/"(\d[.]\d+)"/g, "$1");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            errMsg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            alert(baseErrorMsg + 'Error Code : ' + errMsg);
        }
    })
})();
```

Comment: Add your JSON sample and required output.

Comment: Seems like you have `};` too much in the code, which you posted.